# Print text in table leaving n number of rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I need to print text in cells leaving the row[0] and column[0].
I can make program leave either rows or columns but I don't have an idea about how to make it leave both at the same time.

For now I'm doing this but this is only rows and it's leaving the first ([0]) row in the table to print text but I need the program to leave first ([0]) column too at the same time.

```
docu = docx.Document()
table_x = docu.add_table(rows=5, cols=5)

for row_x in table_x.rows[1:].cells:
    row_x = 'hi'
```

This will just leave rows[0] but I need it to leave columns[0] at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in table_x.rows[1:]:
    for column in row.cells[1:]:
        column.text = 'hi'
```

Comment: Just gives this error
  
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docprac.py", line 70, in <module>
    for col_x in table_x.columns[1:].cells:
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docx/table.py", line 315, in cells
    return tuple(self.table.column_cells(self._index))
  File "/home/udaykhalsa/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/docx/table.py", line 341, in _index
    return self._gridCol.gridCol_idx
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'gridCol_idx'
```

Have you tested this code?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: @inyrface I think you want `for col_x in row_x.cells[1:]` instead for the second line.

Comment: made some edits based on @scanny. Basically you get the iterable at each stage and write text to it.